# What installed in /usr/local are not seen by others

Tags: linux

I often have this issue when configuring a software on linux. When I install some library (for instance `libsodium`) by cloning the repository then doing the usual

```
./autoconf.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

I get everything install in `/usr/local/` which is absolutely good for me.

Unfortunately, when I try to install something that depends on this library (for example `libzmq`, I get the issue

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libsodium) were not met:

No package 'libsodium' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables sodium_CFLAGS
and sodium_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I guess the problem is because `configure` is looking on `usr/` and not `/usr/local`. The ugly workaround is to install everything in `usr/` instead of `/usr/local`. A more brutal approach would be to copy all what is installed in `/usr/local` into `/usr/`.

What is the correct solution when facing this kind of issues?

How should I adjust the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` or the `sodium_LIBS`?

Comment: add /usr/local into PATH?

Comment: `usr/local/bin` is already in my path

Comment: try a soft link? `ln -s` instead of copy all what is installed in `/usr/local` ? should work better.

Comment: @nowox - Adding `/usr/local/bin` vs `/usr/local` is totally different thing. /usr/local contains lib, sbin,etc also.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Well, in my case `$ export PATH=/usr/local/:$PATH` did not help`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/30681)? But it is libsodium specific. IMHO it has nothing to do with the environment, but with the `pkg-config`. Is libsodium present in the output of `pkg-config --list-all`?

Comment: @vlp no it's not listed on `pkg-config --list-all`

Comment: Then probably there is no file `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libsodium.pc`...thus `pkg-config` does not know about libsodium installation.

Comment: @vlp You are right. But `libsodium.pc` was in my `/usr/src/libsodium/` so I copied into the mentionned `pkg-config`. It does not help...

Comment: That said it worked when copied into `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`. Again the same issue then. My installations do not like `/usr/local` as prefix

Comment: does `export sodium_CFLAGS=$(pkg-config libsodium --cflags) ; export sodium_LIBS=$(pkg-config libsodium --libs)` prior to `./configure` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /usr/local by means of your shell.

Some work with export, some with other means.

E. G. 
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/locall

Answer (score 0):

run:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

prior to ./autogen.sh && ./configure.